# react 18 useState and useEffect re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tell me why the re-rendering on the page does not work after the change in userstate
Changes occur after clicking on the page again, and not immediately.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const sortfdb = Datadb.sort((a,b) => b.count - a.count);
    console.log(sortfdb)
    setDatadb(sortfdb);
    console.log(Datadb)
  },[Datadb])
```

I have a field on the page, I will add a number, it writes to useState([]), and when changing the useState, it should sort them. But this is not happening. And it happens only when I add a new number.

useEffect, which catches changes, works, and displays everything in the console as it should, but does not want to change it right away on the page
It worked fine in react 17, but not now. I can't figure out what went wrong

---

### Update

I realized my mistake, I had to provide sort as an array

```
setDatadb(el=>[...el].sort((a,b) => b.count - a.count));
```

But now it throws an error indefinitely, as rendering is constantly happening

```
next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Comment: There is some differences in React 18 So it's recommended to use React 17

Comment: I have already understood this, but I don't see the point in going to the old version when it officially came out on 18

Comment: You should not use setDatadb inside useEffect with setting Datadb as dependency. It will lead to infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating the current state with [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

> The **sort()** method sorts the elements of an array ***in place*** and ***returns
> the sorted array***.

Additionally, the `Datadb` state array reference never changes, so React bails on rerendering because it uses shallow reference equality checks as part of the reconciliation process.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const sortfdb = Datadb.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count); // <-- mutation
  console.log(sortfdb); // <-- sortfdb reference to Datadb state
  setDatadb(sortfdb);   // <-- state reference never changed, no rerender!
  console.log(Datadb);
}, [Datadb]);
```

When you fix the array reference issue, the issue then becomes a hook dependency issue.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // update dependency, render loop!
  setDatadb(el => [...el].sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count));
}, [Datadb]);
```

Don't unconditionally update a value that is in the hook's dependency array as this will trigger a rerender by React and the hook runs again, enqueues the update and triggers another rerender, repeat ad nauseam. This is the render looping error React warns about.

## Solution

If you need to sort the `Datadb` state in an `useEffect` then don't use the `Datadb` state *as* the hook's dependency. Use an empty dependency array or some other value to "trigger" the effect.

Example:

```
const [sortData, setSortData] = React.useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (sortData) {
    setDatadb(data => data.slice().sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count));
    setSortData(false);
  }
}, [sortData]);

...

// some event handler
setSortData(true); // to trigger sorting
```

You might not need the `useEffect` hook at all if all you want to do is sort the `Datadb` state in response to an event. You can/should directly enqueue the state update to sort the data in *that* handler function.

Example:

```
const sortDataByCount = () => {
  setDatadb(data => data.slice().sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count));
};

...

<button type="button" onClick={sortDataByCount}>
  Sort by Count
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

setting state is async, when `console.log(Datadb)` is executed, `setDatadb(sortfdb)` is not yet done. This is the expected behavior even before React 18. However, the state will change, you just can't console log it since it is async...

Comment: I understand how the state works, it's just that before in useEffect I intercepted changes in useState and changed it again as needed. And immediately there was a visual change.

Comment: What I'm saying is you can't console.log the state just after setState since you will still be logging the old state (because setState is async).

Comment: You aren't incorrect about logging the state after an enqueued update, but that's not the issue OP has. OP was mutating the state 3 lines above, so `console.log(Datadb)` is actually logging the "updated" state value *because of the mutation*.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that sort does not provide an array, solved the problem like this:

```
setDatadb(el=>[...el].sort((a,b) => b.count - a.count));
```

I removed the check from useEffect, and moved it immediately after adding a new variable.

There is no infinite loop anymore, in useEffect and most importantly, after adding a new variable, it sorts the values

Answer (score 0):

```
next-dev.js?3515:25 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Updating values to the state should not be done in useEffect. You have to create a function outside and update the state value.

This happens because once if you update a state the reference of the state will be changed and component rerender happens. Again since the reference is changed. The useEffect will be called again and this happens infinitely which the react stops after certain extent.